# Como poner una retícula (mira) a un arma C++ CEGUI

Tags: c++, ogre

Estoy tratando de hacer un mini-juego en OGRE 3D y para crear el MENU estoy usando CEGUI, lo cual no lo veo muy amigable.

Tengo muchísimas dudas y problemas, pero en este post me voy a limitar únicamente a preguntar sobre como poner una retícula.

Ya he visto vídeos, he leído sus tutoriales, visto sus ejemplos y también lo acabo de probar. http://cegui.org.uk/wiki/Sample_code_for_all_Widgets#StaticImage

Lo que creo que me puede servir es ImageStatic, pero resulta que no me compila, por ende, me gustaría que me ayudaran a poder poner una retícula

Mi objeto es poner una imagen que cumpla el rol de una mira, a modo de ejemplo les dejo esta imagen:

Lo que no compila es:

```
    /* StaticImage */
    ImagesetManager::getSingleton().createImagesetFromImageFile("ImageForStaticImage", "GPN-2000-001437.tga");
    DefaultWindow* staticImage = static_cast<DefaultWindow*>(winMgr.getWindow("StaticImage"));
    staticImage->setProperty("Image", "set:ImageForStaticImage image:full_image"); // "full_image" is a default name from CEGUIImageset::Imageset()
```

Ejemplo 1: [MIRA 1](http://www.juegomaniac.com/juegos/imagenes/entrenamientofrancotiradores.jpg)

[image: MIRA 1]

Ejemplo 2: [MIRA 2](https://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/callofduty/images/9/90/Gl_4.png/revision/latest?cb=20120119043641)

[image: MIRA 2]

Comment: Esta pregunta puede llegar a ser muy interesante, pero no tal y como la planteas. Añade algo del código que has intentado crear y describe con más detalle lo que quieres conseguir.

Comment: No tengo nada de código, porque no tengo ni idea como hacerlo, pero lo describo si.

Comment: En la pregunta pones "no me compila", ¿qué no te compila?

Comment: Pronto!! miren  :D

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error de compilación que obtienes?